# Remove Partial View dynamically created in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a repeating partial view , now i want to delete the dynamically created.

This is my Main View `my-custom-row-template` is the partial that will be injected repeatedly onclick.

```
<section class="main_container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()"/></th>
                                        <th scope="col">Setup Responses</th>
                                        <th>Add Condition</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                                        <td scope="col">
                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td scope="col" class="col-xs-10">

                                            <!--<div ng-repeat="condition_set in conditions" my-custom-row-template> </div>-->
                                            <div ng-repeat="condition_set in conditions track by $index"
                                                 my-custom-row-template></div>
                                            <!--<div my-custom-row-template></div>-->
                                        </td>
                                        </td>
                                        <td scope="col">

                                            <input type="button" value="Add Condition" ng-click="addCondition()"
                                                   class="btn btn-primary addnew"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input ng-hide="!personalDetails.length" type="button"
                                           class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
                                           ng-click="remove()" value="Remove">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="Add New">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</span>
```

And this is my Partial view

```
<div class="col-xs-8 pull-left">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <select style="color: black;">
            <option>Response Message</option>
            <option>IF</option>
            <option>Else</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.message"/>
        <select style="color: black;">
            <option>Step 2</option>
        </select>
        <select style="color: black;">
            <option>Add Step</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Remove Condition" ng-click="remove_condition(my-custom-row-template)"
               class="btn btn-danger"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is how i am trying to get the current element and remove it, but i am getting a `0` instead. how to remove the currently clicked Partial ?

```
$scope.remove_condition = function (element) {
                        console.log(element);
                    };
```

Can any 1 tell me on how to remove the current partial view.

Comment: get their index (since you have `$index`) and remove partials with `$scope.conditions.splice(index,1)`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey: this might sound noobish, but is this the correct way to pass the index? 
` ng-click="remove_condition($index)" `

Comment: if it's inside of your `ng-repeat`, then yes. I don't know if this will work if it's inside of the template though

Comment: Yes its on ng-repeat , but ng-repeat is actually repeating the template. And that is what i wanna get.